# What does gnome-settings-daemon is not ready for configuration mean?

Tags: apt, dpkg

On a recent Ubuntu 12.10 install, something innocent like `apt-get install xfonts-75dpi` is giving this message:

```
dpkg: error processing gnome-settings-daemon (--configure):
 package gnome-settings-daemon is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-settings-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I open the Ubuntu Software Center, it says the package is installed.

I don't know what the gnome-settings-daemon is, but I do see it running:

```
hostname:~> ps auxww | grep gnome-settings
username   2468  0.1  0.1 744532 17396 ?        Sl   12:54   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
username   2513  0.0  0.0 452380  9268 ?        Sl   12:54   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
```

What configuration has not been done? How do I get the daemon to be ready for configuration? Or, what diagnostic tools (e.g. logs) are relevant?

Answer (score 2):

It means that during a previous installation, the configure script didn't end or was killed for the gnome-settings-daemon package. This can be solved simply by configuring it

```
sudo dpkg --configure gnome-settings-daemon
```

If it won't budge, you might need to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-settings-daemon
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Unfortunately the system where I needed this is no longer available, so I can't try your answer myself.